# OpenVINO - Inference library plugin libMKLDNNPlugin.so cannot resolve dependency

Tags: c++, openvino

I am experimenting with OpenVINO APIs and below is the sample code snippet:

```
plugin = InferenceEngine::PluginDispatcher(<params>).getPluginByDevice("CPU");
```

However, I get the below error:

```
Cannot find plugin to use :Tried load plugin : MKLDNNPlugin,  error: Plugin MKLDNNPlugin cannot be loaded: cannot load plugin: MKLDNNPlugin from /opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/inference_engine/lib/intel64: Cannot load library '/opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/inference_engine/lib/intel64/libMKLDNNPlugin.so': libmkl_tiny_tbb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I looked for the above missing library and it actually exists:

```
$ ls /opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/inference_engine/external/mkltiny_lnx/lib/
libmkl_tiny_tbb.so
```

It looks like some internal dependency is not resolved by inference engine lib/plugin. Could anyone help figure out why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Add/Update this path

```
/opt/intel/openvino_2019.3.376/inference_engine/external/mkltiny_lnx/lib/
libmkl_tiny_tbb.so
```

into

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 0):

Run a script `setupvars.sh` before you run your program. The script resolves all dependencies needed for running OpenVINO applications.

The script located in `<openvino-install-dir>/bin/setupvars.sh`